# Headers not applying with Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js

My new header arguments will not be applied when I add them to my Fetch method. For example;

```
import { default as fetch } from "node-fetch"

var headers = {
  'Content-Type': "application/json",
  'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15"
}

const WeatherAPI2 = async (lat, lon) => {
  await fetch('https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?' + new URLSearchParams({
    'lat':lat,
    'lon':lon,
    //'altitude': (altitude === null) ? '' : altitude
  }, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers
  })).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
}

WeatherAPI2(60.10,9.58)
```

Will produce the following result:

```
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    type: 'default',
    url: 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.1&lon=9.58',
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: {
      age: '0',
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '84',
      'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Wed, 26 Oct 2022 11:41:31 GMT',
      expires: '0',
      server: 'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)',
      via: '1.1 varnish (Varnish/7.0)',
      'x-backend-host': 'b_157_249_76_16_loc',
      'x-errorclass': 'IllegalUserAgent',
      'x-varnish': '664164654'
    },
    counter: 0,
    highWaterMark: 16384
  }
}
```

I have to use the `User-Agent` for the API to return the successful result.

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc:

> Note: The User-Agent header is no longer forbidden, as per spec — see forbidden header name list (this was implemented in Firefox 43) — it can now be set in a Fetch Headers object, or with the setRequestHeader() method of XMLHttpRequest. However, Chrome will silently drop the header from Fetch requests (see Chromium bug 571722).

So your `User-Agent` might be forbidden with the version you use or silently dropp if you use Chrome.

Regarding the `Content-Type`, I believe that `application/json` should be the default value so you should not need that.

Running:

```js
await fetch('https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58', {
    method: "GET",
    headers:  {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15"
        }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
```

from Firefox console returns me a CORS error.
But by inspecting the developer "Network" tab, I can see that both the  `User-Agent` and `Content-Type` are present in request headers.

Comment: I attempted this before i.e. adding the content type and headers as you did but error still occurs.